# Benefits of Hyper threading in Hadoop Map Reduce

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, hadoop

I am working on setting up a hadoop cluster and was also reading a bit about hyper threading on a separate context where it is said that HT does not always guarantee better performance ["Are there drawbacks?"](http://www.overclock.net/a/hyperthreading-explained) and I wondered as to how Map reduce can actually benefit from HT and what/where these benefits can be observed. They have mentioned here ["Computation"](http://hortonworks.com/blog/6-key-hardware-considerations-for-deploying-hadoop-in-your-environment/), that it helps in process scheduling. However, even in HT, since only one thread is essentially running at a time, what additional performance boost does HT provide in Map Reduce jobs?

Comment: If you can keep most of the threads busy most of the time (probably yes), then go for HT. Otherwise, don't. In any case, measure.

Comment: I am trying to understand what I can do to make most of Hadoop with HT. Any specific way I need to write my MapReduce functions or any specific Hadoop/HBase Region server configurations (Yes, I am using Hadoop with HBase) to make the best use of HT.? Or does it have to be a trial and error approach?